# Как найти минимальный и максимальный элемент из массива

Tags: c++, массивы

В данном случае если у меня есть int n[x] = {...} 
Как мне найти max и min из этого массива.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element не пробовали?

Answer (score 1):

Есть стандартный алгоритм `std::minmax_element`, объявленный в заголовке `<algorithm>`, который находит первый минимальный элемент и последний максимальный элемент в последовательности.

В противном случае, хотя это менее эффективно, вы можете найти минимальный и максимальный элементы массива по отдельности, используя из этого же заголовка алгоритмы `std::min_element` и  `std::max_element`.

Не составляет также большого труда написать соответствующие функции самостоятельно. :)

Вот демонстрационная программа, в которой используются указанные выше стандартные алгоритмы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N];

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    std::generate( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), [=] { return std::rand() % N;} );

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto minmax = std::minmax_element( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );

    std::cout << "Minimum is " << *minmax.first
              << ", maximum is " << *minmax.second 
              << std::endl;


    auto min = std::min_element( a, a + N );
    auto max = std::max_element( a, a + N );

    std::cout << "Minimum is " << *min
              << ", maximum is " << *max 
              << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом

```
9 8 2 3 4 6 1 3 9 0 
Minimum is 0, maximum is 9
Minimum is 0, maximum is 9
```

Comment: Спасибо, а есть код покороче ?

Comment: @Nick Чтобы код был покороче, то можно в явном виде задать значения элементов массива при его определении.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, есть  также std::valarray, который позволит двумя  операциями определит min и max